# Extrair um novo array de um array - Ruby

Tags: array, ruby, array-multidimensional

Tenho a seguinte saída:

```
   => [
        [ 0] [
            [0] "CELULA",
            [1] "LENNA                                 ",
            [4] "jul 01",
            [5] " 2015 12:00:00 AM",
            [6] "N",
        ],
        [ 1] [
            [0] "CELULA",
            [1] "ARI
            [4] "jul 01",
            [5] " 2015 12:00:00 AM",
            [6] "P",
        ],
        ...
     ]
```

Preciso de um novo array semelhante a este só com os itens [1] e [6] deste array.

```
=> [
        [ 0] [
            [0] "LENNA                                 ",
            [1] "N",
        ],
        [ 1] [
            [0] "ARI
            [1] "P",
        ],
       ...
     ]
```

Comment: Poderia formatar melhor os dados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos simplificar um pouco o código e deixar mais "ruby like" :

```
[["CELULA", "LENNA", "JUL 01", "2015 12:00:00 AM", "N"], ["CELULA", "ARI", "JUL 01", "2015 12:00:00 AM", "P"]].map {|e| [e[1], e[4]] }
```

> [["LENNA", "N"], ["ARI", "P"]]

Basicamente criamos um novo Array extraindo apenas o segundo (índice 1) e o quinto (índice 4) elementos do Array.

Comment: Heeey @LuizCarvalho Muito bom! Eu estava tentando algo assim! mas nunca dava certo pois não lembrava de colocar os elementos dentro de um novo array `{|e| [ [elementos] ] }`. Muito Obrigado por responder!

Comment: opa @AristótelesCoutinho por nada! Se a resposta foi útil dá um upvote ai pra incentivar a galera a continuar respondendo! grande abraço!

Answer (score 0):

É importante, deixar o código daquilo que tentou fazer para que o pessoal fique mais motivado a ajuda-lo.

Contudo, aí vai o código que dá-te mais ou menos o que precisas:

```
dados = [["CELULA", "LENNA", "JUL 01", "2015 12:00:00 AM", "N"], ["CELULA", "ARI", "JUL 01", "2015 12:00:00 AM", "P"]]
novo_array = []

dados.each do |x|
  array_filho = []
  array_filho.push(x[1])
  array_filho.push(x.last)

  novo_array.push(array_filho)
end

p novo_array
```

O que se fez?

- Percorremos o array `dados`. E para cada elemento encontrado neste array (que é um outro array), criamos um novo array, com os elementos da segunda e última posição do array encontrado dentro do array `dados`.
- Adicionar o array criado (`array_filho`) no `novo_array`

Comment: Obrigado @psantos . Desculpe por não ter postado o que já havia tentado. Mas tudo que eu consegui fazer foi usando o método `map` e sempre retornava um novo array com os valores em índice único. Eu já havia arrumado uma outra solução, mas pra efeito de estudo quis saber como ficaria a solução como pensei e não consegui fazer rsrs. Vlw!